# Define a initialize method for a Ruby FFI::Struct?

Tags: ruby, ruby-ffi

Currently, I have a RUby FFI Struct:

```rb
class Color < FFI::Struct
  layout :red, :uchar, :green, :uchar, :blue, :uchar
end
```

Which needs to be created like t his:

```rb
color = Color.new
color[:red] = 255
color[:green] = 0
color[:blue] = 0
```

Can I define an `initialize` method on a Struct so that I can just do this:

```rb
color = Color.new(255, 0, 0)
```

I have tried the following which does work, but is it going to bite me down the road somehow?

```rb
class Color < FFI::Struct
layout, :red, :uchar, :green, :uchar, :blue, :uchar
  def initialize(red, green, blue)
    self[:red] = red
    self[:green] = green
    self[:blue] = blue
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The source for `FFI::Struct` (https://github.com/ffi/ffi/blob/master/lib/ffi/struct.rb) doesn't define an `initialize` method, so you aren't overriding anything. This means that what you're doing *should* be fine.

If you wanted to be extra safe, you could always define a new class method on `Color` instead:

```rb
class Color < FFI::Struct
  layout :red, :uchar, :green, :uchar, :blue, :uchar
  def self.from_rgb(red, green, blue)
    color = new
    color[:red] = red
    color[:green] = green
    color[:blue] = blue
    color
  end
end
```

Comment: I did notice `FFI::Struct` had no `initialize` of its own which is one of the reasons I thought I would ask. I wondered if an `initialize` method might be officially added for some reason in the future.  I'll go with your class method suggestion as it is just as convenient. Thanks.